# Incorrect syntax near ',' in F# typeprovider insert query with datacontext

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am trying to insert data through F# typeprovider datacontext. I have a table in database `dbo.tbl_Location`, want to insert data with following simple query.

```
let  InsertTaskDetails() = 
 dbSchema.GetDataContext().DataContext.ExecuteCommand("Insert into dbo.tbl_Location (LocationId,Location) Values (11, 'india')")
 dbSchema.GetDataContext().DataContext.SubmitChanges()
```

But I am getting error:

> Incorrect syntax near ','

I can't understand what's happening when I run the same query in SQL Server 2008

```
Insert into dbo.tbl_Location (LocationId,Location) Values (11, 'india')
```

It works fine. `LocationId` is of `int` type and `Location` is of `string` type.

If somebody has ideas about it please tell me where I am missing the things.

Comment: Er, what kind of DataContext are you using? If it's EF, it doesn't understand SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Craig is right. If you're calling `ExecuteCommand` on an Entity Framework DataContext, you can't pass T-SQL in, because the Entity Framework DataContext only understands [Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx).

Also, when you're directly executing a command like you are, there's no need to call `SubmitChanges` - which is a good thing, because you're calling `SubmitChanges` on a different instance of the data context than you called `ExecuteCommand` on. `GetDataContext` creates an instance each time you call it. If you wanted to do the insert the idiomatic Entity Framework Type Provider Way, it would look more like this:

```
type tbl_Location = dbSchema.ServiceTypes.tbl_Location

let insertTaskDetails () =
    use db = dbSchema.GetDataContext() // it's disposable!
    db.tbl_Locations.AddObject(tbl_Location(LocationId=11, Location="india"))
    db.DataContext.SaveChanges() |> ignore
```